# Using an anchor tag to run and display a query

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a query that returns the data I need, but I would like for it to be able to be called by clicking a link at the top of the page. I have three links at the top, the first two display active and inactive orders when clicked, and I would like the third to display only orders created/reviewed by the currently logged in user.

Everything seems to work independently (query returns what I am looking for from the database, link displays where and how I want it to) but the link simply refreshes the page when clicked currently.

I'm sure there is something simple I am missing here, as I'm very new to ColdFusion. Here is my code spinets with a watered down query (as I don't think that is important.)

QUERY:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(url,"myOrders")>
    <cfquery>
       SELECT * 
       FROM table
       WHERE processorID = #session.user.id#
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

ANCHOR TAG:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="websiteName.cfm?m=#url.m#&ai=1&myOrders=True">My Orders</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you expect that if statement to display something on the page?

Comment: What does `clicked concurrently` mean?

Comment: "the link simply refreshes the page when clicked currently"  Don't quite follow the explanation.  Refreshing the page is what that link is supposed to do. What do you want it to do *instead*?

Comment: You are asking a lot of different questions. You should consider them one at a time. And look up what `<cfqueryparam>` does.

Comment: "clicked currently" was a poor choice of word. In the codes current state, when the link is clicked it doesn't return the query.

I'll look more into <cfqueryparam>. Sorry if it seemed like a lot, I wasn't sure how to word the question. All I want is to make that link show the results of that query on the screen when clicked.

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on so you can see if the query is actually running?

Comment: @Clark - So as not to overlook the obvious, start with some debugging.1. At the top of the page, dump the url scope to verify the expected variable exists AFTER you click the link `<cfdump var"#url#">`2. Temporarily add a `cfelse` clause so you know if the code does NOT hit the cfif block 3. Silly question, but ...does the page contain any code to **display** the query results? Like a `<cfoutput query="...">` loop? Just running the query isn't enough. Nothing will happen if the code doesn't output anything :-)

Comment: 4. It may already be in code we can't see, but... since the link contains CF variables, it must be enclosed in `<cfoutput>` tags, so the variables are evaluated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I'm new to this project, and the existing code was, well, existing when I came on. My query worked (which I'm excited about) but the issue was in a different part of the file there was section that actually displayed the results of a named query.

They had it set up so every query for this particular page had the same name, sorta like:

```
<cfquery name=qDisplayQuery>
```

Once I found this I just put the same name for the query. Now it over rides all other queries when the link is clicked. And each link does the same, so only the query that is associated with the correct link displays when clicked. And thanks @James A Mohler,
I have added `<cfqueryparam>` with some parameters.

Thank you to everyone who lent a hand here, you guys are heros.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set `<cfparam>` to define the expected variables, their datatype and default values.

```
<cfparm name="url.myOrders" type="boolean" default="true">
<cfparm name="url.active" type="boolean" default="true">
```

Next, your links will need to reflect the combinations of these variables. I removed some of the query string parameters to focus on these two. Notice that the last two links do not contain `myOrders`, the first `<cfparam>` handles the default definition of that query string parameter.

```
<ul>
    <a href="websiteName.cfm?myOrders=true&active=true">My Active Orders</a>
    <a href="websiteName.cfm?myOrders=true&active=false">My Inactive Orders</a>
    <a href="websiteName.cfm?active=true">All Active Orders</a>
    <a href="websiteName.cfm?active=false">All Inactive Orders</a>
</ul>
```

Finally, you can dynamically generate your SQL based on these two variables.

```
<cfquery>
    SELECT * 
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        orderStatus = <cfqueryparam value="#url.active#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">
        <cfif url.myOrders>
            AND processorID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.user.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

The `<cfqueryparam>` tags are there to protect against SQL Injection attacks. You can add more variables as needed to change up the SQL you need.